# Control intermediates results in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning, hadoop2

I want to take control of  intermediate results between Map and Reduce with hadoop.
I would want to specify where copy these results after the Map.
I would to choose data which will be  reduced. 
In summary i want  map's results before process shuffle and sort  and do what 
i want.
If you have a solution please tell it me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could process data after your particular mapper get InputSplit. Specify logic into `map` function.

1. > I would want to specify where copy these results after the Map

   use `Context` Java Class and `FileSystem` to flush results on FS
   (local, hdfs, ftp, ...)
2. > I would to choose data which will be reduced
   >
   > i want map's results before process shuffle and sort and do what i
   >   want

   specify logic on your `map` function in `Mapper` Class